# Bootstrap v3.0.1.1 fails on clean VS empty project - how to resolve?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

After creating a new empty MVC4 project in VS 2012 and installing the latest jQuery (2.0.3), the following Nuget package installation errors occur:

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'bootstrap (≥ 3.0.1)'. Attempting to
>   resolve dependency 'jquery (≥ 1.9.0)'. External packages cannot depend
>   on packages that target projects.

Twitter.Bootstrap dated Nov 1, 2013.

Anyone else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Install-Package Bootstrap
```

Instead of

```
Install-Package Twitter.Bootstrap
```